# Split using . returns 0

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String value = "good.day";
String splitValues[] = value.split(".");
System.out.println(splitValues.length);
```

The output of the above code is **0**.I know that split method uses regex. So we have to use escape sequence "\" to make it work.But my question is why this output?. If `.` is a meta character which represents any character, we should get the length of the string as output isn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember when you split, the argument is removed. Thus, when all the characters are split, there are none remaining.

Comment: This is halfway to a good answer.  To earn my upvote, you need to point out that the `split` method explicitly discards trailing empty strings.